# R grouping data with factors and levels

Tags: r, grouping, r-factor

I'm trying to make a frequency table that groups values into a limited number of bins.

Say I have the data

```
X <- c(1,2,3,4,3,9, 20)
```

I can make a frequency table such that it shows all the empty cells like this:

```
(factor(X, levels = c(0:max(X))))
```

Instead of showing the frequency of every possible value, I would like to bin values `>5` so that the levels on the table are: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and >5`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to transform the vector so that it has an unique entry for, then you can add the missing levels in the `factor()` function:

```
X <- c(1,2,3,4,3,9,20)
X <- ifelse(X>5,">5",X)
X <- factor(X,levels=c(0:5,">5"))
```

This results in:

> X
>       [1] 1  2  3  4  3  >5 >5
>       Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5 >5

Comment: Thank you so much. Stuck on this for ages.

Answer (score 1):

Sacha has already given you a working answer, but for future reference, you may want to familiarise yourself with the `cut` function, which is designed to break up a continuous variable into chunks.

```
x <- cut(x, c(-Inf, 0:5, Inf), labels=c(0:5, ">5"))
```